# Explicit conversion from int -> sbyte -> sbyte?

Tags: c#

Given this code snippet

```
[TestMethod]
public void SByte()
{
 int integerValue = -129;
 sbyte sbyteValueFromInt = (sbyte) integerValue;
 Assert.AreEqual(sbyteValueFromInt, 127); // True

 byte byteValue = (byte) integerValue;
 sbyte sbyteValueFromByte= (sbyte) byteValue;
 Assert.AreEqual(sbyteValueFromByte, 127); // True 

 sbyte? nullableSbyte = sbyteValueFromByte;
 Assert.AreEqual(nullableSbyte.Value, 127); // True
 Assert.AreEqual((sbyte)nullableSbyte, 127); // True
 Assert.AreEqual(nullableSbyte, 127); // Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<127 (System.SByte)>. Actual:<127 (System.Int32)>. 
}
```

Why did the last assert failed?

If we dig into the `AreEqual<object>` of `MSTest` then shouldn't it recognize `127` to convert to `sbyte?`?

```
Assert.AreEqual<object>(expected, actual, message, parameters);

public static void AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
 message = Assert.CreateCompleteMessage(message, parameters);
 if (object.Equals((object) expected, (object) actual))
  return;
 Assert.HandleFailure ...
}
```

How come it didn't know how to cast `127` to `sbyte` but it did to `sbyte?`?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi `nullableSbyte.Value` is `sbyte`. `nullableSbyte` is `sbyte?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a <del>bug</del> feature of MSTest. When repeating the test with `NUnit`, or just using `operator ==`, the implicit conversion is honoured.

MSTest's Assert boils down to:

```
Assert.AreEqual<object>(expected, actual, message, parameters);

public static void AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
  message = Assert.CreateCompleteMessage(message, parameters);
  if (object.Equals((object) expected, (object) actual))
    return;
  Assert.HandleFailure ...
}
```

Premature boxing through `object` is likely the culprit.

To get around this, you have to state the obvious to MSTest and provide it with T explicitly, viz:

```
Assert.AreEqual<sbyte?>(nullableSbyte, 127);
```

Which then passes.

By comparison, the NUnit Assert passes without any assistance:

```
    [Test]
    public void SByte()
    {
        sbyte? nullableSbyte = sbyteValueFromByte;
        Assert.AreEqual(nullableSbyte.Value, 127); // True
        Assert.AreEqual(nullableSbyte, 127);
    }
```

As does a poor-man's unit test:

```
    sbyte? nullableSbyte = sbyteValueFromByte;
    if (nullableSbyte.Value != 127)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not Equal");
    }
    if (nullableSbyte != 127)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not Equal");
    }
```

**Edit**

[image: R# comparison]

Comment: If `object` is the culprit, through `boxing` and `unboxing`, shouldn't it honor the `Explicit nullable conversion` in the C# Specification? `An explicit conversion from S to T?`

Comment: I've pasted in a screenshot with R# - it seems that the boxed comparisons will only be true if 127 is converted to an `sbyte` before it is boxed.

Comment: If I do `Assert.AreEqual((object)nullableSbyte.Value, (object)127);`, R# is also saying that `type cast is redundant`. If we dig into the `AreEqual<object>` then shouldn't it recognize `127` to convert to `sbyte`? How come it didn't know how to cast `127` to `sbyte?` but it did to `sbyte`?

Comment: Well, that's why `MSTest` doesn't work here - it leaves it up to `object.Equals` to compare the 2 boxed values (`sbyte` and `int`), which fails (possibly there is a type check involved?). MSTest needed to do more groundwork before just using `object.Equals`, e.g. unboxing both objects after doing null checks and determining if there was an implicit conversion, etc.